# Matlab bisection method

Tags: octave, gnu

I am trying to write a program to find root on GNU octave

```
%this is program to calculate root of Non linear differential eqn

display('you can change function in bsfun.m')
a=input("enter maximum value\t");
b=input("entr minimum value\t");
e=input("enter tolerence\t");
if (bsfun(a)*bsfun(b)>0)
  display("you have not assumed right values")
endif
 
while ((b-a)>e)
  c=(b+a)/2;    %find middile point
  disp c
  if (bsfun(c)==0)    %check middile point is the root 
    break
  elseif (bsfun(a)*bsfun(c)<0)    % Decide the side to repeat the steps
    b=c;
  else 
    a=c;
  endif
end
fprintf("The root is %f\n",c);
```

where

```
%bisection Function
function out = bsfun(x) 
  out = (x.^2)+(2.1*x)-8.82;
```

but it is not working
I am new to programing
also is any way to define user defined function on the first program(with out making separate file Like in c)

Comment: Problem solved Put abs(b-a)

Comment: as `a>b` , `b-a` is always negative, so you should have used `a-b` . You should also add a control that really `a>b`

Comment: yes that was a silly mistake